# Get the index of a tapped item in AdaptiveGridView UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way I can get the index of a tapped item in the AdaptiveGridView toolkit.
Heres my code:
Page Resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Photos">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageText}"
                       FontSize="20">
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

XAML:

```
  <UWPToolkit:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="AdaptiveGV" ItemHeight="200" ItemClick="AdaptiveGV_ItemClick" DesiredWidth="200" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Photos}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    List<Images>   ImageCollection = new List<Images>();

ImageCollection.Add(new Images()
                    {
                        ImageURL = Response[i].ProjectImageURL,
                        ImageText = Response[i].ProjectName

                    });
                }
                AdaptiveGV.ItemsSource = ImageCollection;
```

I want the get an index of the item i clicked. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There's an `ItemClickCommand` property I would assume you could fire off an indexOf method kind of like `collection.IndexOf(clickedItem)` but I haven't worked with that AdaptiveGridView yet, just figured I'd comment since nobody answered yet as a possible route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the get an index of the item i clicked. Is there a way to do that?

Yes you can, in the `ItemClickEventArgs`, you can get the clicked item and its index like this:

```
private void AdaptiveGV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as Images;
    var index = ImageCollection.IndexOf(item);
}
```